Mongo not picking best queryplan
I have a mongo collection with two indexes :
{"token" : 1,"TradeName" : -1 }
{"token" : 1,"Name" : 1 }

All 3 fields token,Name,TradeName are strings.
When I make a query { token : "SOMETHING" , Name : /SOMETHINGELSE/} mongo uses {"token" : 1,"TradeName" : -1 } index.
Can someone explain to me why this hapenning?
Does the index not make a difference because its regex?
Execution plan that won :
{
                "nReturned" : 30,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 730,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 730,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "filter" : {
                        "Name" : /JOSE/
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 30,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 731,
                    "advanced" : 30,
                    "needTime" : 700,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 18,
                    "restoreState" : 18,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 730,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "nReturned" : 730,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 731,
                        "advanced" : 730,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 18,
                        "restoreState" : 18,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "token" : 1,
                            "TradeName" : -1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "token_1_TradeName_-1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "token" : [ ],
                            "TradeName" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "token" : [
                                "[\"IRENO\", \"IRENO\"]"
                            ],
                            "TradeName" : [
                                "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 730,
                        "seeks" : 1,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            }

Execution plan of { token :1 , Name:1 }
{
                "nReturned" : 30,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 731,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 30,
                "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "nReturned" : 30,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                    "works" : 731,
                    "advanced" : 30,
                    "needTime" : 700,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 19,
                    "restoreState" : 19,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "docsExamined" : 30,
                    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "Name" : /JOSE/
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 30,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                        "works" : 731,
                        "advanced" : 30,
                        "needTime" : 700,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 19,
                        "restoreState" : 19,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "keyPattern" : {
                            "token" : 1,
                            "Name" : 1
                        },
                        "indexName" : "token_1_Name_1",
                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                        "multiKeyPaths" : {
                            "token" : [ ],
                            "Name" : [ ]
                        },
                        "isUnique" : false,
                        "isSparse" : false,
                        "isPartial" : false,
                        "indexVersion" : 2,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "indexBounds" : {
                            "token" : [
                                "[\"IRENO\", \"IRENO\"]"
                            ],
                            "Name" : [
                                "[\"\", {})",
                                "[/JOSE/, /JOSE/]"
                            ]
                        },
                        "keysExamined" : 731,
                        "seeks" : 1,
                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                    }
                }
            }


Maybe this answer can answer your question?

This doesn't answer why mongo thought the index with TradeName was better. Althought not as efficient as text index, the index with Name should help with search.

More debugging details are required then, like sample json documents, exact index definition, exact query and explain result... Currently, it is not reproducible in playground. It is consistently using the index with the field Name

.explain("allPlansExecution") output for the query please

Why do you think the other index is bettee? If the regex cannot use the index, then it doesn't matter which of these indexes are used.

I added the execution plans of both queries.

Note that both execution plans required 731 units of work to return 30 documents  Since both performed equally well, one was randomly chosen.  Also note that the plan using { token :1 , Name:1 } took 10ms longer to complete, so with the current data set, that index is not better for this query.

But why is second field not making a difference?

When mongodb plans a query, it runs a test execution using all potential indexes.
The test will run until one of the following is true:

one of the plans completes
one of the plans returns 101 documents
10,000 units of work are performed

It then scores the plans for number of documents returned per unit of work, with a bonus if the plan reached completion during the test, and a bonus if the plan did not require an in-memory sort.
If multiple indexes score the same, one is randomly chosen.
Once a query shape has been planned, that plan is cached and re-used for future executions of the same query shapre.
If you want to see which indexes were considered and how they fared, run the query using explain with the allPlansExectution option.

I added the execution plans of both queries
